# Guessing game doesn't accept third variant of answer

Tags: javascript

I did a guessing game with the example from video lesson, but if i write the right answer on the third time, it says that i did not guess. The problem is there: `if(tryCount == maxTryCount)`? This code down below is from lesson.

```
var answer = parseInt(Math.random() * 100);
var userAnswer = +prompt("Угадай число от 0 до 100");
var maxTryCount = 5;

for(var tryCount = 1; tryCount < maxTryCount; tryCount++){
    if(userAnswer == answer){
        alert("Поздравляю, ты угадал!");
        break;      
    } else if(userAnswer > answer){
        alert("Ты ввёл слишком большое число.");
    } else if(userAnswer < answer){
        alert("Ты ввёл слишком маленькое число.");
    }

    userAnswer = +prompt("Попробуй ещё раз. Введи число от 1 до 100\n У тебя осталось " + (maxTryCount - tryCount) + " попыток");
}
if(tryCount == maxTryCount)
    alert("Ты проиграл!");
alert("Правильный ответ: " + answer);
```

Comment: Read [this article](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) for tips on debugging your code.

Comment: Start `tryCount` at 0 or change the loop condition to `<=`.

Comment: @blackbrandt, yes, you are right.

Comment: @Zac Anger, THANK YOU, i didn't knew how to do this so neatly)

Comment: @shmosel, if I change the loop condition to <=, then the third variant is accepted, but after it a loss window pops up, because if(tryCount == maxTryCount)
    alert("Ты проиграл!); (You lost!)

Comment: @shmosel, If I start tryAccount from 0 it will give me 4 tries but the last one is still losing.

Answer (score 1):

I did it! If I change the loop condition to `<=` and change `if(tryCount == maxTryCount)` to `if(tryCount > maxTryCount)` then the third variant is accepted as "right".

Comment: This is what we call an "off by one error".